# How to un-indent code using the Ace editor on koding.com?

Tags: ace-editor

indent code using the Ace editor on koding.com?

With Sublime you can do <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> , but I can't find an equivalent on koding.com. Please don't reply with code because I'm not asking how to configure an Ace editor. I am asking how to use the Ace editor that appears on koding.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to un-indent. This also works in Sublime.